# CSS Grid Layout on iOS, Android - trouble with grid-template-areas

Tags: android, ios, css, css-grid

See simplified code below. The code is working fine on a windows desktop with chrome (header and footer show side my side on full screen, and on a shrunken screen below 480px, the header is shown below footer).

But Android and iOS devices with chrome (v59) seem to ignore "grid-template-areas" altogether, and display the areas in default (html) order vertically. 
Is there something wrong with my code? Or is it a limitation on iOS and Android?

```css
.header {
  grid-area: hd;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: ft;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "ft" "hd";
}

@media (min-width:440px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr 4fr;
    grid-template-areas: "hd         hd         ft"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class=header>Header</div>
  <div class=footer>Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether or not you're new to responsive design, but when I started I had a similar problem.

I had a fully responsive website on my PC. I could resize the browser and it was doing what I wanted. But on my phone, I had the basic version and I didn't understand why it wasn't using the media query styles.

Turns out I forgot to add this to my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Hope it helped

**EDIT:** Tried your sample on my phone, android with latest chrome, works fine!
https://jsfiddle.net/7mpkb817/

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is working on my android phone. It still is not working in iOS for me, but on further investigation, CSS Grid Layout needs iOS10.3, which  won't work on my iPhone4s. I will have to upgrade my hardware!